# How to convert date fr to en from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2016

Can someone tell me how to convert a SQL date from a French language SQL Server 2005 to a date in an English language SQL Server 2016? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 SELECT
     CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CREDAT_0, 103) + ' ' + CAST(CRETIM_0 / 3600 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST((CRETIM_0 - ((CRETIM_0 / 3600) * 3600)) / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':00' AS DATETIME) AS DateCreation
 FROM 
     x3.STOLOC
```

**Edit**: actually, I'm trying to update some stored procedure but every date time was in French, and now they're in English. So I'm trying to convert a French date to an English date. Both servers should work together and keep the same stored procedure (no change in parameter, just a change in corpus to convert the date).

Thanks for helping

Comment: SQL dates do not need to be converted.  They are stored using an internal format.  Use `convert()` or `format()` to output the string format that you prefer.

Comment: format doesn't exists in sql server 2005 so I can't use it. Both stored procedure should work

Comment: what do you mean by from sql server 2005 to sql server 2016?

Comment: What type is credat_0? And cretim_0? You don't need to convert anything if it is stored as DateTime.

Comment: there is a stored procedure in sql server 2005 which I want to export in sql server 2016. But sql server 2005 is french and sql server 2016 is english and the data are the same (excepted date format). Both need to work together, so I have to convert en date to french date.

Comment: I need to use same procedure with an entry datetime in french format.Credat_0 as datetime and Cretim_0 as integer. When i use stored procedure, it crashs on parameter conversion on sql server 2016 and work fine on sql server 2005. The parameter is sent by an external application (from french format)

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Here is the error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.